# Mariadb Columnstore restore Lock table command is currently not supported in Columnstore

Tags: mariadb, columnstore

I am getting below error while restoring database that upto 20GB size file.

ERROR 1178 (42000) at line 2254: The storage engine for the table doesn't support IDB-2029: Lock table command is currently not supported in Columnstore.

Any one know what is the exact issue here.

This is the restore command I am using for mariadb columnstore restore 
/usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/mysql/bin/mysql --socket=/usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/mysql/lib/mysql/mysql.sock -o mydatabase < /home/mydatabase/databasedump.sql

Comment: What version of MariaDB did the source come from?  What was the dump command?

Comment: mariadb columnstore version 1.1.5, trying to restore by source mysql.sql file, after some time it showing Lock table issue.

Comment: Show us the full command that created the dump file.  That is where the `LOCK` statement comes from.